# Magento google sitemap - category path in products urls

Tags: magento, sitemap

Im encountering a new problem related to magento google sitemap.

How can i add category path to products urls inside xml sitemap?
I'd like to know how to modify the output in order to resolve my problem.

All the best!

Comment: I think you have to do it yourself because Magento doesn't provide this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If your product has a category id (check $product->getCategoryId() ) you can use

```
$product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params) ;
```

$params array MUSTN'T contain the "_ignore_category" index

Answer (score 0):

The problem to put categories is teach to Magento what category use.

For instance, your product can be on "category-1/category-1-2/" and "category2/".

The most easily way is create one new attribute called "main_category" and into your sitemap put this code

```
$base = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
$categoryUrl = $product->getAttributeText('main_category');
 if($categoryUrl !== NULL):
$base.$categoryUrl.$product->getData('url_path');
 else:
$base.$product->getData('url_path');
 endif;
```